# How can I login with a js and jquery modal on my website in next.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I would like to be able to login through my modal, but I can't find a solution to call my function that validates the form, let alone get the values of my variables.
My modal:

```
$(function () {
//URL BASE DO PROJETO
getBase = $("link[rel='http://localhost:3000']").attr("href");

$(".jtheme_login").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!$(".theme_login").length) {
        var loginBox = '<div class="theme_login">';
        loginBox += '<div class="theme_login_box radius">';
        loginBox += '<header>';
        loginBox += '<h1>Fazer Login:</h1>';
        loginBox += '<p>Informe seu nome e e-mail para fazer login e acessar seus pedidos.</p>';
        loginBox += '</header>';
        loginBox += '<form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>';
        loginBox += '<input class="radius" type="email" name="email" value={user.email} onChange={handleChange()} placeholder="E-mail:"/>';
        loginBox += '<input class="radius" type="password" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={handleChange()} placeholder="Senha:"/>';
        loginBox += '<a class="btn transition radius icon-success" href="/admin/orders" title="Minha conta">Fazer Login</a>';
        loginBox += '</form>';
        loginBox += '<button href="#" title="Recuperar senha" class="theme_login_box_recover transition icon-alert" type="submit">Esqueci minha senha</button>';
        loginBox += '</div>';
        loginBox += '</div>';

        $("body").prepend(loginBox);
        $(".theme_login").fadeIn(200).css("display", "flex");

        $("body").click(function (e) {
            if ($(e.target).attr("class") === "theme_login") {
                $(".theme_login").fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

For you to better understand my problem, my StaticHeader.js component where I call the modal with the click on the login that has the jtheme_login class:

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import Router, { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import { handleLogout } from '../../utils/auth';
import ModalLogin from './ModalLogin';

Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => NProgress.start();
Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => NProgress.done();
Router.onRouteChangeError = () => NProgress.done();

const INITIAL_USER = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
};

const StaticHeader = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(INITIAL_USER);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = React.useState(true);
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const [error, setError] = React.useState('');

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const isUser = Object.values(user).every(el => Boolean(el));
        isUser ? setDisabled(false) : setDisabled(true)
    }, [user]);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setUser(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    }

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            setLoading(true);
            setError('');
            const url = `${baseUrl}/api/login`;
            const payload = {...user};
            const response = await axios.post(url, payload);
            handleLogin(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            catchErrors(error, setError);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
        console.log(handleChange)
    }

    const router = useRouter();
    const [menuActive, setMenuActive] = React.useState(false);
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState({search: ''})
    // console.log(user)
    const isRoot = user && user.role == 'root';
    const isAdmin = user && user.role == 'admin';
    const isRootOrAdmin = isRoot || isAdmin;

    const isActive = (route) => {
        return route == router.pathname;
    }

    const handleOnChange = (e) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        setSearch(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: value}) )
    }

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        Router.push({
            pathname: '/products',
            query: {term: search.search}
        })
    }

    const menuToggle = () => {
        setMenuActive(!menuActive)
    }

    return (
        <header className="main_header">
        <div className="container">
            <div className="main_header_nav">
                <div className="main_header_nav_logo">
                    <a href="" title="WdpShoes | Home">
                        <img alt="logo" title="logo menu" src="/css/themes/logo/wdpshoes_logo_white.png" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div className="main_header_nav_search">
                    <form action="" method="post" className="radius">
                        <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Pesquisar na loja:" />
                        <button className="icon-search icon-notext transition"></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="main_header_nav_menu">
                    <a className="icon-cart icon-notext transition main_header_nav_menu_cart" href="/cart"><span>3</span></a>
                    <div className="main_header_nav_menu_user">
                        <a href="#" title="#" className="icon-user main_header_nav_menu_user_a radius transition jtheme_login">Login</a>
                        <nav className="radius">
                            <a href="#">Meus Pedidos</a>
                            <a href="#">Meus Pedeidos</a>
                            <a href="#">Meus endereços</a>
                            <a href="#">Sair</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul className="main_header_departments">
                <li className="main_header_departments_li">
                    Departamento
                    <ul className="main_header_departments_li_ul">
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li className="main_header_departments_li">
                    Departamento
                    <ul className="main_header_departments_li_ul">
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li className="main_header_departments_li">
                    Departamento
                    <ul className="main_header_departments_li_ul">
                        <li className="main_header_deprtaments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li className="main_header_departments_li">
                    Departamento
                    <ul className="main_header_departments_li_ul">
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                        <li className="main_header_departments_li_ul_li"><a href="">Categoria</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    );
}

export default StaticHeader;
```

But when I try to change the form I get an error:
ReferenceError: handleChange is not defined

My big problem is that it is possible for me to interact my modal form with the functions of my component to be able to login, can someone help me how I could do that?
thanks

Comment: Why do you use jQuery on a React/Next.js site?

Comment: Because first I work with html css and js, then I try to move to react next.js and I'm in the process of learning, trying to find alternatives to solve this type of problem that leaves me frustrated in several projects